# Bounding $\|e^{2\pi iq}-1\|$ for $q$ an almost idempotent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra, and let $q\in A$ such that $\|q^2-q\|<\varepsilon$, and $\|q\|<K$.

**Question:**
How small does $\varepsilon$ need to be (possibly in terms of $K$) to guarantee that

$$\|e^{2\pi iq}-1_A\|<1?$$

Comment: How can $e^{2\pi iq}$ be homotopic to anything, being a complex number instead of a mapping?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I believe they are using the holomorphic functional calculus. $e^a$ is a well-defined element for any (unital) C*-algebra $A$ (even Banach algebra) and $a \in A$.

Comment: I guess you don't even need functional calculus to write $e^a$ as an element of a Banach algebra. Its exactly what you'd think it would be as an infinite sum.

Comment: @PStheman I know what $e^{2\pi iq}$ is. My question is what it means to call that exponential "homotopic" to something. (Oh, I see I said "complex number" in my comment. Sorry...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No problem. Fair, maybe OP should clarify, but I will anyway. By homotopy (via invertibles), they just mean there exists a continuous path $\xi: [0,1] \to GL(A)$ with $\xi(0) = e^{2\pi iq}$ and $\xi(1) = 1$ (or vice versa). For unital C*-algebras, the norm inequality they have implies homotopy (there is a more general inequality that works for two elements $a,b$).

Comment: @PStheman I assumed that that couldn't be the question because that's so obvious: $\xi(t)=e^{(1-t)2\pi iq}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks, this is a good point which I had overlooked in trying to write down the question in a simple form! Let me modify the question. (In the setting I'm actually looking at, $A$ is a quotient $B/I$ for some ideal $I$, $q\in A$ is an idempotent modulo $I$, hence $e^{2\pi i q}\in I^+$. The thing I want to do is find when $e^{2pi iq}$ and $1$ are homotopic through invertibles in $I$. This is still guaranteed by the (strictly stronger) condition that $\|e^{2\pi iq}-1\|<1$.)

Comment: Does such a bound always exist? Consider the $C^\star$ algebra $A$ to be $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$, and $q$ to be $(1,0)$. $q$ is an idempotent (an exact one, rather than an approximate one), but $|| e^{2\pi i q} - 1_A ||$ is always equal to 1, and never less. Please let me know if I am missing something (according to the current form of the question, edited by @geometrick ~1hr ago...). I think some additional criterion on $q$ might be needed?...

Comment: @UjanChakraborty If $q$ is an idempotent, then $e^{2\pi iq}=1$. How is multiplication on $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ defined, and which element is $1_A$?

Comment: @geometricK, $\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ is a $C^\star$ algebra thus: the addition is done componentwise, the multiplication is given by $((a,b),(c,d))\mapsto (ac,bd)$, the involution is given by pointwise complex conjugation, and the norm being $||(a,b)||=Max\{|a|,|b|\}$. Then, $1_{\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}} = (1,1)$. It appears to me that $q=(1,0)$ is an idempotent as $q^2=q$, but $e^{2\pi i q}\neq 1$. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @Ujan, $e^{2\pi i q} =  1 $ because   $$
  e^{2\pi iq} =   e^{2\pi i(0, 1)} = (e^{2\pi i\times 0},e^{2\pi i\times 1}) = (1,1) = 1_A
  $$

Comment: @Ujan, In fact for every idempotent $q$ in any normed algebra one has
  $$
  e^{2\pi iq} =   \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi  i q)^n}{n!} =
  1 +  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi  i)^nq}{n!} =
  1 +  (e^{2\pi  i}-1)q = 1
  $$

Comment: @Ruy, of course: a computation error on my part! Thanks for the proof in the general case!

Comment: @Ujan, in case you thought that
  $
  (2\pi  i q)^n = (2\pi  i)^nq,
  $
  for every $n$ (ignoring the possibility that $n=0$), then welcome to the team!  I must admit I've done it too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a numerical condition by bounding the terms in the sum. Like the others I don't know what you mean with homotopic. Start with

$$\|q^n-q\| = \|q^{n-2}(q^2-q)+q^{n-1}-q \| < \epsilon K^{n-2} +\|q^{n-1}-q\| $$
so by induction
$$\|q^n-q\| < \epsilon \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} K^{n-2-k} =  \epsilon K^{-2} \dfrac{1-K^{n}}{1-K}$$
(for $K\neq 1$). Making use of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(i2\pi)^k}{k!}=0$ we may evaluate
$$e^{i2\pi q}-1 =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(i 2\pi)^k q^k}{k!}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(i2\pi)^k(q^k-q)}{k!}$$
Applying the bound we have derived for $q^k-q$ retrieves:
$$\|e^{i2\pi q}-1\| < \epsilon \frac{K^{-2}}{1-K}\sum_k \frac{(2\pi)^k(1-K^n)}{k!}= \epsilon\  \frac{e^{2\pi K}-e^{2\pi}}{K^3-K^2}$$
which provides you with a condition on $\epsilon$ depending on $K$. This bound is definitely not optimal.

Comment: In case you're interested, I've asked a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986165/exponentiating-an-almost-idempotent-and-almost-self-adjoint-element

Comment: Why is this bound not optimal?

Comment: Because it diverges as $K\to 0$, im sure the entire region $K<1$ admits significantly better bounds.