# Exponentiating an almost idempotent and almost self-adjoint element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra, and let $q\in A$ be such that $\|q^2-q\|<\varepsilon$, and $\|q\|<K$.

In answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982325/bounding-e2-pi-iq-1-for-q-an-almost-idempotent), s.harp showed that

$$\|e^{2\pi iq}-1_A\| < \varepsilon\ \frac{e^{2\pi K}-e^{2\pi}}{K^3-K^2}.$$

On the other hand, for any $s\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$|e^{2\pi is}-1| < 2\pi|s|.$$
Using this, a better bound should be possible in the case that $q$ is self-adjoint, or, more generally, close to self-adjoint.

**Question:** Suppose $q$ also satisfies $\|q-q^*\|<\delta$ in addition to the above. Then is it possible to improve the above bound for $\|e^{2\pi iq} - 1_A\|$ by taking $\delta$ into account?

Comment: Just a remark, if $q$ is self-adjoint looks like the best bound is given by
$$\sup_{x\in B_{R}(0)}|e^{i2\pi x}- 1|$$
(here $R=\sqrt{\epsilon+1/4}-1/2$), this is $<1$ iff $\epsilon < \frac{\pi^2}9 + \frac{\pi}3$.

Comment: If $q$ is self-adjoint, the Spectral Mapping Thorem implies that
  $$
  \|e^{2\pi  i q}-1\| = \sup_{s\in \sigma (q)}|e^{2\pi  i t}-1|.
  $$
  On the other hand, by Exercise 2.2.7 in [Rordam, Larsen, Laustsen, "An Introduction to K-Theory
for C*-Algebras",  LMS 49], it is possible to approximate a quasi-selfadjoint,  quasi-idempotent
element by a projection, so this should lead to a better bound.

Comment: @s.harp How do you get $R=\sqrt{\varepsilon+1/4}-1/2$?

Comment: For normal elements the spectrum tells you the norm. So for what real numbers $r$ is $|r(1-r)|< \epsilon$? There are two scenarios, either $r$ is close to $0$ or close $1$, for $r$ close to zero you may solve the inequality to get $|r|< \sqrt{1/4 + \epsilon}-1/2$. For $r$ close to $1$ you get the same inequality for $|r-1|$. So in the expression of the comment you need to take the superemum over the union of the balls $B_R(0)$ and $B_R(1)$, however since $e^{2\pi i x}$ has period one it suffices to just look at the ball over $0$.

Comment: @s.harp I see. There are couple more things I wonder if you could clarify. First, could you derive the last inequality in your answer? I tried applying the self-adjoint case, but only get something like $\sup_{x\in B_R(0)}|e^{\pi ix}-1|\leq\sqrt{2(1-\cos(2\pi R))}$. Also, should the bound for the first term, $C\frac{\delta}{2}$, be $C\pi\delta$? I get $e^{z\frac{q+q^*}{2}}-e^{zq}=\int_0^1 dt\ z\frac{q^*-q}{2}e^{zt\frac{q^*-q}{2}+zq}$, which gives $C\pi\delta$ as the bound.

Comment: You are right on both counts, I had forgotten the $z$ when differentiating and to take the root of the complex case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a calculation yielding better bounds, but its probably very far away from optimal. The gain is that *there is* a uniform bound in $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Fix some constants:

$$K:=\|q\|, \quad z:= 2\pi i, \quad C:=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\|\exp( z \,t \,(q-q^*)/2+ zq)\|$$
(one bound of $C$ is $e^{\pi\delta}e^{2\pi K}$, but thats probably a bad bound).

One bound I can get is the following:

> If $\epsilon + (K+1)\frac{\delta}2<\frac{\pi^2}9+\frac{\pi}3$ then:
> $$\|e^{i2\pi q}-1\|≤C\frac \delta2+\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos(2\pi R (\epsilon, \delta) )\right)}$$
> With $R(\epsilon,\delta)= \sqrt{1/4 + \epsilon +(K+1)\frac\delta2}- 1/2$.

The only hard part is the bookkeeping, the path is conceptually simple start with:

$$\|\exp( z\,q)-1\| ≤ \|\exp(z\,q)-\exp(z\frac{q+q^*}2)\|+\|\exp(z\frac{q+q^*}2)-1\|\tag{$*$}$$
now since $q$ is close to $q^*$ we will see if this makes the first term small and since $\frac{q+q^*}2$ is hermitian we will apply the inequality from the hermitian case.

For the first term note:

$$\exp(z\,q)-\exp(z\frac{q+q^*}2) = \left[\exp(zt\,(q-q^*)/2+ zq)\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}=z\int_0^1dt \frac{q-q^*}2 \exp(zt\,(q-q^*)/2+ zq)$$
taking the norm and pulling it into the integral yields that the first term of $(*)$ is smaller than $\pi\,C\,\delta$.

For the second term compute:
$$\|\frac{q+q^*}2(1-\frac{q+q^*}2)\| ≤ \begin{split}\frac14\left( \|q(1-q)\|+\|q^*(1-q^*)\|+\|q^*(1-q^*)+(q-q^*)(1-q^*)\|+\\ \|q(1-q)+(q^*-q)(1-q)\|\right)\end{split}$$
which you further simplify to $\epsilon +(K+1)\frac\delta2$.

Now you may apply the hermitian case to $\frac{q+q^*}2$ using $\epsilon + (K+1)\frac{\delta}2$ as the parameter. This yields, provided $\epsilon + (K+1)\frac{\delta}2<\frac{\pi^2}9+\frac\pi3$, that
$$\|e^{i2\pi (q+q^*)/2}-1\|≤\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos(2\pi R(\epsilon, \delta))\right)}$$